# We were unable to find the authorization token in LinkedIn

Tags: java, android, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I have been searching the answer for this question from many days, but still did not get the solution.

For sharing data using LinkedIn, after sign-in option in LinkedIn I'm getting "We were unable to find the authorization token" this message, instead of going to "user permission request page".

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared details of your implementation, but most likely you're missing a step during the authentication process. I would review the Authentication document to ensure you're handling authentication correctly: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication